# Как генерировать уникальный ключ для JWT, если его не рекомендуется хранить в базе ?

Tags: php, jwt

Использую вот эту библиотеку: https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt
Как видно, для того, чтобы зашифровать/расшифровать токен необходим секретный ключ.

Если я хочу для безопасности для каждого токена генерировать свой уникальный ключ, то как я узнаю у кого, какой ключ если не буду хранить токеты в базе данных ?

Как кто, подходит к этому вопросу ?

Comment: а чего вы опасаетесь? почему ключ не может быть один и тот же?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать уникальный ключ, то его придется где-то хранить, так как он должен быть полностью случайным. Это может быть БД, может быть файл, но сути это не меняет.

Но создавать для каждого токена уникальный ключ смысла нет. Это лишь усложнит решение, а это скорей всего приведет к ухудшению безопасности.